# How to delete a node with a particular value?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, infinite-loop

I am trying to delete a node with a particular value. The way my node is set up is as such:

```
typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
};


typedef struct {
  /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
  Node *head;
} List;
```

Currently, my list looks like this (each integer below represents the id from the : 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 7

I would like to delete 1 and 4, so the resulting linked list looks like this: 
2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7

I have written the code below. In the method, `key` represents the value, and the node with that value should be deleted.

```
void delete(int key, List *list)
{
  //If linked list is empty (base case):
  if (list->head == NULL) {
    printf("Invalid command\n");
    exit(EXIT_BAD_INPUT);
  }

  //Store head node
  Node *temp = list->head;

  //If first node needs to be deleted (special case):
  if (key == list->head->id) {
    list->head = temp->next; //Change head
    free(temp); //Free old head
  } else {
    //Find previous node of the node to be deleted
    while (temp->id != key) {
      temp = temp->next;
    }

    //If the position is more than the number of nodes, throw exception:
    if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL) {
      printf("Invalid command\n");
      exit(EXIT_BAD_INPUT);
    }

    //Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
    //Store the pointer to the next of node to be deleted
    Node *next = temp->next->next;

    //Unlink the node from the linked list
    free(temp->next);
    temp->next = next;
    printf("RECORD DELETED: %d\n", key);
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I receive `Segmentation Fault: 11`. Could someone please assist me with deletes nodes with particular values and at the end of the list? In addition, how can I check if the key value is not present in the linked list? Apologies in advance if this is a duplication question.

Comment: Side note. `/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */` The comment is wrong, there's no tail pointer. This is a good example why comments which repeat what's in the code should be deleted; it's very easy for them to fall out of sync with the code. Instead, comments are to explain *why* the code is the way it is.

Comment: @Schwern thank you for catching that, I just edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Could you show how you're initializing the nodes? If it's using stack memory, `free` will not work.

Comment: If it really is a single linked list, you could always [just do this](https://pastebin.com/HxgFzYLD). If that isn't the case (managing a tail pointer, a fore-and-aft linked list, etc.) it gets more complicated.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's clever, holding a pointer to the next pointer. Could you explain it in an answer?

Comment: @Schwern It's already in at least one answer below. You analysis in your first sentance (holding a pointer to the next pointer) is a wonderful explanation in itself, btw. Nice. I prefer that method because it requires no additional if-else for head management. For non-ptr2ptr implementations, Genes answer below is about as good as it gets, and is easy to understand as well.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer to pointer method is okay, but there's really nothing complex about using two pointers that march down the list.  Just be consistent. There's a lead and trail pointer. When the lead finds the element to delete, use the trail to update its `next`. The exception is when the trail is null. This means the lead is pointing to the head element, so update the head pointer instead.

```
/** delete node with value key from list */
void del_node (int key, List *list)
{
  for (Node *p = list->head, *q = NULL; p; q = p, p = p->next) // p leads, q trails
    if (p->data == key) {
      if (q) q->next = p->next;
      else list->head = p->next;
      free(p);
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If instead of using a pointer to keep track of the previous and next nodes, you use a ***double pointer*** (e.g. address of the pointer) to the current node, there are no special cases, e.g.

```
/** delete node with value key from list */
void del_node (int key, List *list)
{
    Node **pn = &list->head;    /* pointer to pointer */
    Node *n = list->head;       /* pointer to node */

    while (n) {                 /* iterate over nodes */
        if (n->id == key) {     /* if key found */
            *pn = n->next;      /* set address to next */
            free (n);           /* delete current */
            break;              /* done */
        }
        pn = &n->next;          /* address of next */
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

There is a very nice write-up on why this makes matters much simpler at [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to find both the note which matches, and its previous node.

We can loop until we find a match or the end of the list, remembering the previous node. By starting with `list->head` there's no special case needed for the first node.

```
Node *match = list->head;
Node *prev = NULL;
while( match && (match->id != key) ) {
    prev = match;
    match = match->next;
}
```

If there's no match the loop will exit and `match` will be null. You're done.

```
if( !match ) {
    return NULL;
}
```

Otherwise we remove the matching node by changing the previous node's next to be the match's next. If there is no previous node, we change the head to be the next node. If it matches the last node, no harm done; `match->next` will be null so `prev->next` will be null, the new end of the list.

```
if( prev ) {
    prev->next = match->next;
}
else {
    list->head = match->next;
}
```

Finally, what to do with the deleted node? You could `free` it within the function as you are. This is acceptable if you have full control over all the node memory. If you don't, this might result in an error if the node is allocated on the [stack](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html).

It's more flexible to return the deleted node and let the user do what they want with it. This is the typical behavior when deleting from a key/value structure: return the value. This is why I'm returning `NULL` above when we don't find anything.

```
return match;
```

At minimum, return a boolean to indicate whether something was deleted.

You might use it like so.

```
int main() {
    Node node3 = { .id = 3, .next = NULL };
    Node node2 = { .id = 2, .next = &node3 };
    Node node1 = { .id = 1, .next = &node2 };
    List list = { .head = &node1 };

    Node *deleted = delete(3, &list);

    if( deleted ) {
        printf("Deleted id = %d\n", deleted->id);
    }
    else {
        puts("Node not found");
    }

    for(
        Node *node = list.head;
        node;
        node = node->next
    ) {
        printf("id = %d\n", node->id);
    }
}
```

---

I believe your mistake is here.

```
//Find previous node of the node to be deleted
while (temp->id != key) {
  temp = temp->next;
}
```

This does not find the previous node, it finds the matching node.

Furthermore, `free` only works if the node was allocated with `malloc` on the heap. If it was allocated on the stack it will not work. For example...

```
// This is all allocated on the stack an cannot be free()d
Node node3 = { .id = 3, .next = NULL };
Node node2 = { .id = 2, .next = &node3 };
Node node1 = { .id = 1, .next = &node2 };
List list = { .head = &node1 };

delete(2, &list);
```

Which is why I'd recommend returning the deleted node and let the user handle it. Or take full control over the list's memory and write an `add_node` function that handles memory allocation.